# Why is the user ID values passed to Google Analytics not showing in GA?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've setup the User ID tracking, and looking at my source code, the ID of the authenticated WordPress users is being passed to Google Analytics.

[Source code showing User ID in code for GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgS1h.png)

[Console showing user id being passed to GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TfBw.png)

I also enabled User ID tracking for that Google Analytics account, but I can't see the user IDs in Google Analytics.

[Google Analytics User Explorer not showing user IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkrHn.png)

I setup a custom segment to only show data for users with a user ID, and the segment seems to work... but I still can't see the user ID that I pass to GA in Google Analytics.

[Custom segment for users with user ID value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG5Vi.png)

[UserID Coverage report in GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSxcl.png)

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: User Id tracking requires to set up a specific view, which records data only for sessions where the user id is set, and does show the user id (at least it does for me).

Answer (score 1):

To track User ID reporting, you would have to create a new User ID view. Just make sure that you have User ID enabled when creating the view. [Look at step 7 for creating  new view - Official Documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714)

User-ID Views can't be converted to standard views, and standard views cannot be converted to User ID views. Only new views that are in the User-ID enabled property can be designated as User-ID Views.